# Do PCB printed fractal antennas have nulls orthogonal to PCB?

Tags: antenna

I know the printed strip antenna I am using now (on a NRF52DK) has two nulls along the axis of the antenna, parallel to the PCB.  I know a whip antenna sticking out of the PCB has nulls in the direction of the whip (orthogonal to the PCB.)  What is the direction of the nulls of a fractal antenna printed on a PCB?  Because I want a printed antenna, and to install my PCB flat, and have uniform reception in the plane of the earth's surface.

Comment: An ideal isotropic antenna in one plane has 0dB gain.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I don't know the correct lingo.  My mental image is of donuts.  I picture a whip antenna oriented up to have a pattern (gain?) of a donut laying flat.  I think my strip antenna on a PCB laying flat has a pattern of a donut on its edge.  I ask whether a fractal antenna on a flat PCB has a pattern of a donut laying flat (same as wire whip?)   Most what I read about fractal antennas is about their multi-frequency benefits, but I am wondering whether another benefit is that it rotates the pattern by ninety degrees?

Comment: This one appears to have null strength from the bottom feed. https://emcos.com/images/Applications/App_Antenna4_Fractal_Antennas_Results_2.gif